# Многозадачность компьютеров

Tags: многопоточность, таймер, ос

Насколько я понимаю, процессы в компьютере выполняются не совсем параллельно, а на самом деле быстро переключаются между собой. Но в таком случае время на завершение всех процессов все равно остается таким же, как если бы процессы работали последовательно. Правильно ли я понимаю, что главная фишка этой как-бы "параллельности" в том что мы можем не дожидаться пока некий процесс закончится а перейти на другой остановив предыдущие? Какие еще преимущества у такого принципа "параллельности"?

В таком случае, если принцип как-бы "параллельности" верен, то разве в часах на компьютере не должно накапливаться отставание?

Comment: компьютерные часы работают без процессора, ибо для этого есть тактовый генератор

Comment: Ок, с часами понял. А, к примеру, если мы откроем два видео сразу? Почему они корректно работают?

Comment: псевдомнагозадачность позваляет выполнять несколько задач одновременно незаметно для вашего глаза :) ну а если серьезно то это в нескольких словах не объяснить.

Comment: А незаметность для моего глаза было шуткой?

Comment: нет, кратким описанием скорости работы процессов :)

Comment: @Hashirama два видео работают корректно, потому что компьютер разделяет их загрузку и отображение на много маленьких задач и быстро переключается между ними. К примеру, нарисовал 1 кадр одного видео, нарисовал кадр другого видео. На самом деле все сложнее но принцип примерно такой.

Comment: еще добавлю ложку меда в бочку дегтя - на многоядерных процессорах многозадачность для каждого ядра своя и для всех ядер своя - это уже как двухмерный массив а на многопроцессорных платах  с многоядерными процессорами - это уже как трехмерный массив

Answer (score 4):

Ответ зависит от того, что делают ваши процессы или потоки (давайте для простоты дальше будем говорить о потоках, которые в оригинале зовутся thread). Потоки будут выполняться действительно одновременно, если у вас есть больше одного ядра.

Но в вопросе, как я понимаю, интересует ситуация, когда ядро одно. В этом случае некоторые потоки все равно могут выполняться параллельно. Например, пока жесткий диск читает данные или сетевая карта получает пакеты, то операционная система может переключиться на другой поток, и в таких задачах будет заметен выигрыш. Если вы отправили некоторые данные на звуковую карту, то можете пока заняться другими делами, пока она не проиграет полученный участок звука.

Если же у вас несколько потоков, которые заняты в основном расчетами, которые занимают ядро процессора, то в этом случае выигрыша от распараллеливания не будет, и даже будет замедление, т.к. переключение между потоками - это не очень дешевая операция.

Answer (score 2):

> Насколько я понимаю, процессы в компьютере выполняются не совсем параллельно, а на самом деле быстро переключаются между собой.

В современных многозадачных операционных системах это действительно так, но в общем случае это зависит от операционной системы.

> Но в таком случае время на завершение всех процессов все равно остается таким же, как если бы процессы работали последовательно.

Да, если вся полезная нагрузка процессов выполняется именно на процессоре. А это далеко не всегда так. Различный ввод-вывод приводит к простою процессора. Если во время этого простоя выполнять код другого процесса, можно сэкономить время.

Правда, это не учитывает расходы времени на т. н. *context switch* ("переключение контекста", переход управления из процесса в процесс), так что чисто ЦПУшные задачи при "распараллеливании" окажутся даже медленнее.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что главная фишка этой как-бы "параллельности" в том что мы можем не дожидаться пока некий процесс закончится а перейти на другой остановив предыдущие?

Да, я выше примерно это и описал :) Другие процессы могут быть и не "силой" остановлены. Они могут остановиться сами в ожидании результата от ядра ОС.

> Какие еще преимущества у такого принципа "параллельности"?

Вообще это не "параллельность" как таковая, но хорошего перевода правильного термина, concurrency, я пока не слышал. "Конкурентность" разве что.

Concurrency имеет место, когда код структурирован не для последовательного выполнения, а содержит определённые "разветвления" и "соединения", разные ветки которых могут (потенциально) исполняться параллельно. Однако не обязаны. И описанный вами механизм как раз позволяет "конкурентному" коду ужиться на одном процессоре.

Достаточно часто конкурентный код используется в рамках **одного** процесса (в разных *потоках* [thread]), в котором поддерживается какой-то интерфейс пользователя (UI), а из него запускается какая-то рабочая нагрузка. Они оформляются конкурентно, чтобы интерфейсом можно было пользоваться даже когда программа занята какой-то работой.

Однако это "преимущество" строится скорее на способе определения понятия "процесс".

Скажем, в Linux различий между "процессом" и "потоком" минимум: у них всех есть собственные "process ID", хотя снаружи их не всегда видно, т. к. перечислители процессов стараются отдельные потоки не показывать, за ненадобностью.

Но этот же принцип встречается и в несколько неожиданной форме: интерпретаторы некоторых языков, в частности Ruby (MRI), JS (V8) и Python (CPython), реализованы с применением Global Interpreter Lock, и из-за этого интерпретатор в каждый момент времени может заниматься выполнением только одного потока кода. Это **существенно упрощает реализацию интерпретатора** и взаимодействующего с ним кода (расширений на С, например), хотя и ставит дополнительные ограничения.

> В таком случае, если принцип как-бы "параллельности" верен, то разве в часах на компьютере не должно накапливаться отставание?

Да нет, там всё в порядке, поддержкой часов обычно занимается отдельное устройство ([RTC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) с батарейкой), а не процесс.

Иначе как бы часы шли, когда компьютер выключен? Впрочем, это легко выяснить. К примеру, на всех моделях Raspberry Pi часы при каждом включении приходится выставлять заново. Там реализована поддержка часов при включенном устройстве, но отдельного источника питания для них нет. Похожим образом будет себя вести и обычный настольный компьютер, если извлечь из материнской платы батарейку.